# What caused the invalid virtual address in linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, panic

Update: the virtual address is invalid address, not null pointer.

=======================================================

Invalid virtual address problem happened in my project, but I did not modify the code, some information as below:

```
[ 1150.456387] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0000000000010000
[ 1150.456393] Mem abort info:
[ 1150.456395]   ESR = 0x96000005
[ 1150.456398]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[ 1150.456400]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[ 1150.456402]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[ 1150.456404]   FSC = 0x05: level 1 translation fault
[ 1150.456407] Data abort info:
[ 1150.456409]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000005
[ 1150.456411]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[ 1150.456413] user pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgdp=00000008e7572000
[ 1150.456415] [0000000000010000] pgd=0000000000000000, p4d=0000000000000000, pud=0000000000000000
[ 1150.456676] Internal error: Oops: 96000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[ 1150.456802] Skip md ftrace buffer dump for: 0xa00f50

[ 1150.457154] pc : percpu_ref_get_many+0x2c/0x104
[ 1150.457164] lr : percpu_ref_get_many+0x2c/0x104
[ 1150.457167] sp : ffffffc02e513a20
[ 1150.457168] x29: ffffffc02e513a20 x28: ffffffef9324a000 x27: fffffffe00000008
[ 1150.457171] x26: fffffffe00000000 x25: 0000008000000000 x24: ffffff88661d3800
[ 1150.457175] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffffff8970f94408 x21: 0000000000000001
[ 1150.457178] x20: 0000000000010000 x19: 0000000000000001 x18: ffffffc01ce1b078
[ 1150.457181] x17: 430e0000071d4992 x16: 0001400000000000 x15: 000000008e83ddb6
[ 1150.457184] x14: 00000000ab032363 x13: 00000000d860b6cd x12: ffffff88661d4230
[ 1150.457187] x11: ffffffef93f46de8 x10: 0000000000000018 x9 : 0000000000000080
[ 1150.457190] x8 : 00000000000000c0 x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffffffef910a04c0
[ 1150.457192] x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000002
[ 1150.457195] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : ffffffef92f6e370 x0 : 0000000000000005
[ 1150.457198] Call trace:
[ 1150.457199]  percpu_ref_get_many+0x2c/0x104
[ 1150.457202]  refill_obj_stock.llvm.3785610425212570905+0xa8/0x24c
[ 1150.457208]  memcg_slab_free_hook+0x138/0x1a8
[ 1150.457212]  kmem_cache_free+0x14c/0x378
[ 1150.457214]  unlink_anon_vmas+0x60/0x1e0
[ 1150.457217]  free_pgtables+0x54/0x190
[ 1150.457219]  unmap_region+0xfc/0x148
[ 1150.457223]  __do_munmap+0x588/0x79c
[ 1150.457225]  __vm_munmap.llvm.11919687734878218350+0x88/0x174
[ 1150.457228]  __arm64_sys_munmap+0x44/0x5c
[ 1150.457231]  invoke_syscall+0x60/0x150
[ 1150.457235]  el0_svc_common.llvm.8274709215075016746+0xc8/0x114
[ 1150.457237]  do_el0_svc+0x28/0xa0
[ 1150.457239]  el0_svc+0x28/0x90
[ 1150.457243]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0x88/0xec
[ 1150.457246]  el0t_64_sync+0x1b4/0x1b8
[ 1150.457250] Code: 9402597f b0014e20 91196000 97fb46b8 (f8bfc289)
```

I parsed the information with the tool `crash`. The invalid address problem happened on the line `percpu_ptr = READ_ONCE(ref->percpu_count_ptr);` as below:

```
/*
 * Internal helper.  Don't use outside percpu-refcount proper.  The
 * function doesn't return the pointer and let the caller test it for NULL
 * because doing so forces the compiler to generate two conditional
 * branches as it can't assume that @ref->percpu_count is not NULL.
 */
static inline bool __ref_is_percpu(struct percpu_ref *ref,
                      unsigned long __percpu **percpu_countp)
{
    unsigned long percpu_ptr;

    /*
     * The value of @ref->percpu_count_ptr is tested for
     * !__PERCPU_REF_ATOMIC, which may be set asynchronously, and then
     * used as a pointer.  If the compiler generates a separate fetch
     * when using it as a pointer, __PERCPU_REF_ATOMIC may be set in
     * between contaminating the pointer value, meaning that
     * READ_ONCE() is required when fetching it.
     *
     * The dependency ordering from the READ_ONCE() pairs
     * with smp_store_release() in __percpu_ref_switch_to_percpu().
     */
    percpu_ptr = READ_ONCE(ref->percpu_count_ptr);

    /*
     * Theoretically, the following could test just ATOMIC; however,
     * then we'd have to mask off DEAD separately as DEAD may be
     * visible without ATOMIC if we race with percpu_ref_kill().  DEAD
     * implies ATOMIC anyway.  Test them together.
     */
    if (unlikely(percpu_ptr & __PERCPU_REF_ATOMIC_DEAD))
        return false;

    *percpu_countp = (unsigned long __percpu *)percpu_ptr;
    return true;
}
```

Another case happend on line `if (unlikely(percpu_ptr & __PERCPU_REF_ATOMIC_DEAD))`.

pointer variable `ref` comes from an address `&objcg->refcnt` as blow:

```
static inline void obj_cgroup_get(struct obj_cgroup *objcg)
{
    percpu_ref_get(&objcg->refcnt);
}
```

So it cann't be invalid. Why did invalid address problem happened?

Comment: "So it cann't be null" - Why do you think so? If `objcg` is NULL, then `&objcg->refcnt` is NULL too, because `refcnt` is the first field of `struct obj_cgroup`. In general, if you modify Linux kernel (or one of its modules) and crash stack trace doesn't include your code, then the most possible reason that your code **corrupts** some kernel data. Corruption cannot be debugged by simple looking into the stack trace and the code it represents.

Comment: The invalid address is 0000000000010000, not NULL

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your help.  If `objcg` was null, I think the problem would happened ealier on code `percpu_ref_get(&objcg->refcnt);`.  Since  `ref` is obtained by an variable's address, I don't it could be null pointer. Besides, the problem happened many times, it seems not random code corrupts.

Comment: @stark You are right. it is my mistake.